# in python, for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, algorithm, encode

I want to make an encoding algorithm. So I wrote this code. but doesn't work (Python).

### Encoding algorithm

example : "11101"

encoding algorithm

=> ([0]+[1]) + ([0]+[1]+[2]) + ([1]+[2]+[3]) + ([2]+[3]+[4]) + ([3]+[4])

=> (1+1) + (1+1+1) + (1+1+0) + (1+0+1) + (0+1)

=> result = 23221

### Code

```
  def encode(n):
      result=""
      for i in range(0, len(n)):
          if i==0:
            result+=str(int(n[i])+int(n[i+1]))
          elif i==(len(n-1)):
            result+=str(int(n[i-1])+int(n[i]))
          else:
            result+=str(int(n[i-1])+int(n[i])+int(n[i+1]))
      print result
```

If I use "encode("11101")", it doesn't work...

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > File "", line 1, in
> >
> > encode("1101")
> >
> > File "", line 6, in encode
> >
> > elif i==(len(n-1)):
> >
> > TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

What can I do in this situation? How modify the code to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
elif i==(len(n-1))
```

This is the line in question. You're trying to subtract 1 from a string. I think what you actually want to do is:

```
len(n)-1
```

In order to avoid bugs like these you should give your variables speaking names.
input_string might be a good fit here.